# How to disable overflow:hidden on third nesting level in nav menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu and when I use pseudo class "hover" all ul inside my `class="block"` appear.

I want to inside ul's will appear only when my mouse will on it. How can I do it using overflow? That's my code:

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/Trich1121/pen/WNJwxjw)

Comment: Have you tried giving `block` class to every `<ul>` in your html?

Comment: I've tried but it did not help